# Mouse Gesture Libraries for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse, gesture-recognition, gesture

Are there any half decent mouse gesture libraries for .Net? Have found very few and no decent ones.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but found this one on Codeplex:

[Mouse Gestures for .NET](http://mousegestures.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that gesture and multitouch support will be in .NET 4. Beta 2 of Visual Studio 2010 is available on MSDN, and will be in public beta October 21. That's one place you need to look.

How that would interact with a mouse, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting article and code at code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/cmgblade.aspx